# Angular JS - ng-change not getting triggered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive for showing a **X** besides a text box for clearing the data inside the text box,

**Directive JS**

```
angular.module(appName).directive('clrTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            cntrlas: '=',
            mdlval: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.cleartxt = function () {
                scope.cntrlas[scope.mdlval] = '';
            }
        },
        template: '<button class="close-icon" type="reset" id="closeicon" ng-click="cleartxt()" ><img src="/resources/img/quote-tool-close.png" class="clear-icon"></button>'
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.epinNumber" ng-change="numberLengthCheck(item)" >
<clr-txt cntrlas="item" mdlval="'epinNumber'"></clr-txt>
```

This will create a **X** icon at the end of the text box and will clear the data when you click on it.

The issue is, I'm triggering a function `on-change` , So when the **X** icon is clicked, the data will be cleared and so ideally. the change event should be triggered. But for some reason the change event is not triggered when the data is cleared using the **X** directive.

Comment: inside directive `cleartxt` function after clearing value  write `scope.$ctrl.numberLengthCheck(scope.cntrlas);` .Check if that  trigger the function

Comment: I believe you're not binding `epinNumber` to your directive properly. In the <input> element you reference the value as `item.epinNumber`; whereas in your element directive you reference the value as `epinNumber`.

Comment: As Trent said also I see you are passing string value in quote so in directive you should have `@` binding for `mdlval`

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to set `bindToController`and `controllerAs` alias.then you can access the controller function inside link function of directive.

```
angular.module('plunker', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Test';
   $scope.numberLengthCheck = function(n){
        alert('change triggered '+ n);
   };
}


angular.module('plunker').directive('clrTxt', function(){

  return {        
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
            cntrlas: '='
    },

    templateUrl: 'reverse_template.html',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrls) {
      scope.cleartxt = function () {
            scope.cntrlas = '';
            scope.numberLengthCheck(scope.cntrlas);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In **ng-change** the  expression is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model. If you want to listen the model **$watch** is useful

And here I think no need of sending extra attributes (cntrlas,mdlval) to `clrTxt`directive. You can access the parent scope in directive by making `scope:false` which is default.

Directive JS

```
app.directive('clrTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
       template: '<button type="reset" ng-click="cleartxt()" >X</button>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.cleartxt = function () {
                scope.item.epinNumber = '';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Controller JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.$watch('item.epinNumber', function(newvalue,oldvalue) {
        console.log('new value is ='+newvalue+ ' and old value is ='+oldvalue);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.epinNumber">
    <clr-txt ></clr-txt>
    {{item.epinNumber}}
  </body>
```

Here is the working plunker [LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ss0HwAHXU8LPrlvV7CfW?p=preview)

Comment: The problem is, there is a list of items and for each item there will be a text box. How can we add watch for all the text boxes. that is not possible na. !

Comment: In that case you can invoke the method directly from directive after setting model to empty.

Comment: i tried this approach, and $watch is also not triggered when value change is from the directive